# Not equal to check with propel

Tags: php, propel

I want to check not equal to condition with propel how can I do this? I tried it with filter by method, but it is not working. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Code:-

`$school = models\SchoolQuery::create() ->joinWith('Course') ->where("SchoolType <> 0") ->orderBySchoolName('asc') ->find()->toArray()`

Comment: can we see your code what you have tried so far?

Comment: Previously I had used filter by and then I tried with where condition. Please look up the code below @Anant     $school  = models\SchoolQuery::create()
            ->joinWith('Course')
            ->where("SchoolType <> 0")
            ->orderBySchoolName('asc')
            ->find()->toArray();

Comment: In my opinion the code should work. Which errors do you get? Do which table does the column 'ShoolType' belong to and what datatype does it have?

Comment: I got rid of it. There was actually an intermediate table in between..Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$school = models\SchoolQuery::create()
    ->joinWith('Course')
    ->filterBySchoolType(0, CRITERIA::NOT_EQUAL)
    ->orderBySchoolName() // asc is default, so you can ommit it
    ->find()
    ->toArray();
```